# ? User cannot access Initiation form for Sharepoint 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, infopath, designer-workflow

I've created a workflow for a Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Infopath FOrms library.
Even with the default initiation form, a user with full control permissions on the library gets the following error when trying to manually start the workflow:

> A form template (.xsn) file cannot be accessed. You may not have the required     permissions to open the file.

I can start the workflow with no problem with my site collection admin accounts.

What can I do?

Comment: Does the person starting the WF have permissions on the site in general? Does the InfoPath form link to other lists or libraries with different permissions?

Comment: 1. yes, even with full control permission on the site, no change.
2. The form is not really an issue, but she is able to load, edit, etc. with the form from the browser.